# How do I get object id in sonata_type_collection associated admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a Symfony 2.0 with SonataAdminBundle 2.0. This is a method from one of my admin controllers.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('events', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array(
            'edit'      => 'inline',
            'inline'    => 'table'
        ))
    ;

    $this->getFormFieldDescription('events')
        ->setAssociationAdmin($this->getConfigurationPool() >getInstance('platform.admin.events'));
}
```

and I have associated eventsAdmin controller with this method

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $currentObjectId = '' // this is what I want???

    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('time')
        ->add('trigger')
    ;
}
```

So my parent form looks like

**Name**: blablabla
**Events**:
 
1. - delete1 - name1 - time1 - trigger
2. - delete2 - name2 - time2 - trigger
3. - delete3 - name3 - time3 - trigger

What I want is to get an ID of current object in associated admin.. "Trigger" is a select box and it's dependent on current object id. I have to make a query with it.

There is a method **->getSubject()** in **Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin** but it always returns the first "event" object.

Any suggestions?